# f and g are bounded with domain of integers and target the real numbers . If f/g is bounded, then g/f is bounded.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have come up with two bounded functions f = 1/x^2+1 and g = 1/x^2+2 and these tell me that g/f is also bounded. However, I am having trouble writing a proof or proving that g/f is not bounded by showing some counter example.

-> Would it be possible to prove using arbitrary constant values like M and N ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. Let $g(x)=1$, $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac1x \text{ for }x >1 \\
1 \text{ for } x\leq 1\end{cases}$.

Then $|f(x)|<2$ and $|g(x)|<2$ for all $x$. Also $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=|f(x)|<2$ but $g(x)=\begin{cases} x \text{ for }x >1 \\
1 \text{ for } x\leq 1\end{cases}$ is unbounded.

Comment: what is χ[1,∞)1/x

Comment: Edited to be clearer.

Comment: is the piecewise function f bounded ? Because we are told that both f and g are bounded.

Comment: I think i'm a little confused with the concept of "bounded" can you please explain it.

Comment: A function, $f$ is bounded if there is a $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x$